# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic3

Estoy creando una app en ionic
Es una app de asistencias que tiene un servicio.
Y el html contiene un ngfor y un {{ note.name }}
y al momento de clickear en los nombre, me devulve el error cannot read property 'name' undefined

Aca les dejo el codigo
Home html

```
<ion-header><ion-navbar><ion-title>1º 1º</ion-title></ion-navbar></ion-header>


<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let note of notes" (click)="subir()" >
      {{ note.name }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-fab right bottom>
      <button ion-fab ><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>

</ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Añadir11Page } from "../añadir11/añadir11";
import { NoteService } from "../../service/notes.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-manana11',
  templateUrl: 'manana11.html',
})
export class Manana11Page {

notes = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public noteService : NoteService) {
    this.notes = noteService.getNotes();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Manana11Page');
  }

public subir(){
  this.navCtrl.push( Añadir11Page );
}

}
```

y el servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class NoteService{
  note = [
    {id:1, name: "Reymundo Nahuel"},
    {id:2, name: "Alumno2"},
    {id:3, name: "Alumno3"}
  ];
  public getNotes(){
    return this.note;
  }

}
```

Añadir11Page

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Añadir alumno</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>

   <ion-item>
     <ion-label fixed>Nombre y apellido</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="note.name"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>1/2 A</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox color="green" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>1/2 T</ion-label>
 <ion-checkbox color="green" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>1/4 A</ion-label>
 <ion-checkbox color="green" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>AA A</ion-label>
 <ion-checkbox color="green" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>AA T</ion-label>
 <ion-checkbox color="green" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
 <div padding>
   <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="createNote()" >Añadir</button>
 </div>
```

Añadir11 TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-añadir11',
  templateUrl: 'añadir11.html',
})
export class Añadir11Page {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl:ViewController) {
}
}
```

Comment: Buenas, tendrías que añadir el código del page Añadir11Page que es donde se encuentra el error, ya que en el código que muestras todo es correcto.

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadi a la publicacion!

Comment: El componente `Añadir11` no tiene una propiedad `note` que bindear. PD: **No uses nunca** caracteres especiales como `ñ` por cuestión de compatiblidad y buenas prácticas.

Comment: A mi me está pasando esto, y hago un console.log de la propiedad que me salta este error(en este caso la mia se llama (_id) y llega el dato, pero me sigue saliendo undefined. Lo lograste solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Ya intuía que usabas la variable note en la page Añadir11.
Lo que tienes que haces es pasar como parámetro el note que quieres al hacer push.
Ejemplo:

public subir(note){
       this.navCtrl.push( Añadir11Page, {
          "id": note.id,
          "nombre": note.name
       });
   }

Y en el controlador de Añadir11 recuperar los datos de la siguiente manera :

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl:ViewController) {
     let id = navParams.get('id');
     let nombre= navParams.get('nombre');
}
```

Tienes que cambiar esto en el html:

```
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let note of notes" (click)="subir(note)" >
      {{ note.name }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Recuerda que tienes que pasar los parámetros estos no se pasan solos. Trata de revisar bien que los elementos que llames estén definidos.

Comment: En el codigo this.navCtrl.push( Añadir11Page, {
  "id": note.id,
  "nombre": note.name
});. No me encuentra los parametros note :/

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que te funcione. Si te he servido marcalo como respuesta y cualquier duda me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en tu **ion-list** al entrar a la vista el **ngFor** intentara recorrer todo el array, antes de que este cargue. Por lo tanto te recomiendo usar **ngIf**

agrega la siguiente linea y va a funcionar

```
<ion-list *ngIf="notes">
```